# Doubt in kernel based method - unit hypercube(Parzan window estimate)

Tags: machine-learning, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing, pattern-recognition

I recently started studying pattern recognition on my own. Please clarify me the following.

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=T0S0BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=hypercube+of+side+h&source=bl&ots=jMaXtIbzki&sig=ACfU3U3gWUMyzkjZ7V1lEUIdy6W4F9180g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ55ivxqHoAhW5zjgGHWQzBe8Q6AEwEXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=hypercube%20of%20side%20h&f=false

In kernel based method, if $ \phi(u)$ is hypercube of side 1 in d-dimension, then $\phi(\frac{u-u_0}{h})$ must be hypercube centered at $u_0$ and side decreased by factor (1/h) right?(ie., side of hypercube now = 1/h right?) But the book says side of hypercube = h. (In fact such function defination is assumed to show that it is a kernel function in later part). Kindly explain.

Again he writes as $\forall u_n, \phi(\frac{u-u_n}{h})$ is 1 if $u_n$ falls inside that hypercube and 0 otherwise(how is he concluding that? I know $\phi(\frac{u-u_0}{h})$ is hypercube of dimension 1/h centered at $u_0$). Please explain.

Comment: This is purely a matter of arithmetic.  Choose $d=1$ and plug in a few values to see.  For instance, when $u-u_0 = h$ the fraction in the argument is $(u-u_0)/h = 1.$

Comment: understood sir, thank you